# Null pointer exception using Spring ldap

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, ldap

I'm trying to access some datas in a Ldap directory. To do so, I use Spring Ldap.
I found out recently there is a magical way to use it, aka the DirContextAdapter. However, when I could browse the registry without problems using the old-fashion way, I'm getting NullPointerException in this case.

Here is the dao I made following the [documentation exemple](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.x/reference/html/dirobjectfactory.html) :

```
@Component
public class DynSubscriberDao {

    @Autowired
    private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;

    public void create(DynSubscriber subscriber) {
        DirContextAdapter context = new DirContextAdapter(buildDn(subscriber));
        mapToContext(subscriber, context);
        ldapTemplate.bind(context);
    }

    public void update(DynSubscriber subscriber) {
        Name dn = buildDn(subscriber);
        DirContextOperations contextOperations = ldapTemplate.lookupContext(dn);
        mapToContext(subscriber, contextOperations);
        ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(contextOperations);
    }

    public void delete(DynSubscriber subscriber) {
        ldapTemplate.unbind(buildDn(subscriber));
    }

    public List findByFullName(String fullName) {
        AndFilter filter = new AndFilter();
        filter.and(new EqualsFilter("objectclass", "DynSubscriber")).and(
                new WhitespaceWildcardsFilter("cn", fullName));
        return ldapTemplate.search(DistinguishedName.EMPTY_PATH,
                filter.encode(), getContextMapper());
    }

    public List findByName(String name) {
        AndFilter filter = new AndFilter();
        filter.and(new EqualsFilter("objectclass", "DynSubscriber")).and(
                new WhitespaceWildcardsFilter("cn", name));
        return ldapTemplate.search(DistinguishedName.EMPTY_PATH,
                filter.encode(), getContextMapper());
    }

    public List findAll() {
        System.out.println(getContextMapper().toString());
        EqualsFilter filter = new EqualsFilter("objectclass", "DynSubscriber");
        return ldapTemplate.search(DistinguishedName.EMPTY_PATH,
                filter.encode(), getContextMapper());
    }

    protected ContextMapper getContextMapper() {
        return new DynSubscriberContextMapper();
    }

    protected Name buildDn(DynSubscriber subscriber) {
        return buildDn(subscriber.getFullName());
    }

    protected Name buildDn(String fullName) {
        DistinguishedName dn = new DistinguishedName();
        dn.add("cn", fullName);
        return dn;
    }

    protected void mapToContext(DynSubscriber subscriber, DirContextOperations context) {
        context.setAttributeValues("objectclass", new String[] { "top", "person",
                "DynSubscriber" });
        context.setAttributeValue("cn", subscriber.getFullName());
    }

    private static class DynSubscriberContextMapper extends AbstractContextMapper {
        public Object doMapFromContext(DirContextOperations context) {
            DynSubscriber DynSubscriber = new DynSubscriber();
            DynSubscriber.setFullName(context.getStringAttribute("cn"));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the an searched object DN : cn=toto,dc=dynamease,dc=net
The ldapTemplate bean is defined as follows :

```
<bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
    <property name="url" value="ldap://192.168.1.10:10389" />
    <property name="base" value="dc=dynamease,dc=net" />
    <property name="userDn" value="uid=admin,ou=system" />
    <property name="password" value="secret" />
</bean>
```

Right now, DynSubscriberDao.findAll() throws the aforementioned exception. I already checked classnames, by the way ;)

Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? I am experiencing the same problem in my environment and I am actively looking for a solution. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: I did, but I'm afraid I don't have access to the code anymore. I'll give it a try and tell you if I manage to redebug this :)